# Locally bypassing hyperref

Tags: hyperref

I want to make the hyperref package skip some `\ref` commands in my TeX file and not make them hyperlinks in the resulting pdf document.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

---

Here is an example where I would like hyperref bypassed:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\writeval}[2]{%
\@bsphack%
\protected@write\@auxout{}%
{\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}}}%
\protected@write\@auxout{}%
\@esphack%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{counter}


\begin{document}

\writeval{mylabel}{6}
mylabel = \protect\ref{mylabel}\\

\begin{tabular}{c}%
  \setcounter{counter}{1}%
  \whiledo{\thecounter<\ref{mylabel}}{%
    {\thecounter}\\ % 
    \stepcounter{counter}%
  }%
\end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: `hyperref` provides the `NoHyper` environment for this.

Comment: @StephanLehmke, can you give a link to a reference. I can't find it in [hyperref manual](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html).

Comment: Your `\writelabel` macro appears to be patterned closely after the standard-LaTeX `\label` command. Do note that `hyperref` redefines both `\label` and `\ref` quite significantly. Thus, the version of `\ref` that's available once `hyperref` is loaded is rather unlikely to be able to retrieve what you wrote to the `.aux` file via a `\writelabel` command (since hyperref's `\ref` and `\ref*` macros expect a rather different label structure). You should probably define your own `\readlabel` command, likely patterned after the `\ref` macro defined in the file `latex.ltx` (the "LaTeX kernel").

Comment: @Kaveh Unfortunately `hyperref` is famous for fragmentary documentation; it's much better to look into the source code :-) In the source doc, you'll find that environment in section "23 Localized nullifying of package". But as Mico already mentioned, you'll never be able to use `\ref` as long as you bake your own `\writelabel` incompatible with `hyperref`s interpretation of labels.

Answer (score 10):

Yes: Use `\ref*` instead of `\ref` to create a cross-reference that's not also a hyperlink.

A simple example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}\label{sec:1}
abc    
\section{Next section}\label{sec:2}
def    
\section{Final section}\label{sec:3}    
A hyperlinked cross-reference to Section \ref{sec:1}, 
and an ordinary cross-reference to Section \ref*{sec:2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did try `\ref*` but it doesn't work for me. (I am writing some labels into the AUX and then using \ref to read their values. Hyperref tries to make them hyperlinks and causes errors, `\ref*` doesn't return the correct values.)

Comment: @Kaveh - Please provide a bit more information about the errors you're getting. Please also provide more information on how you are writing labels to the `.aux` file and reading them back in using `\ref`.

Comment: I added a small example.

Answer (score 4):

This solution consists in providing a `\hyperbypass` macro that patches the hyperref driver locally (if you don't want to replace the relevant `\ref`s with `\ref*`s) and a `\hyperrestore` macro to restore the previous settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
%Store the hyperref driver setup
\let\HR@hyper@@anchor\hyper@@anchor
\let\HR@hyper@link\hyper@link%
\let\HR@hyper@linkurl\hyper@linkurl%
\let\HR@hyper@linkfile\hyper@linkfile%
\let\HR@hyper@anchorstart\hyper@anchorstart
\let\HR@hyper@anchorend\hyper@anchorend
\let\HR@hyper@linkstart\hyper@linkstart
\let\HR@hyper@linkend\hyper@linkend
%Bypass macro
\newcommand\hyperbypass{%
\let\hyper@@anchor\@gobble
\gdef\hyper@link##1##2##3{##3}%
\def\hyper@linkurl##1##2{##1}%
\def\hyper@linkfile##1##2##3{##1}%
\let\hyper@anchorstart\@gobble
\let\hyper@anchorend\@empty
\let\hyper@linkstart\@gobbletwo
\let\hyper@linkend\@empty
}
%Restore macro
\newcommand\hyperrestore{%
\let\hyper@@anchor\HR@hyper@@anchor
\let\hyper@link\HR@hyper@link%
\let\hyper@linkurl\HR@hyper@linkurl%
\let\hyper@linkfile\HR@hyper@linkfile%
\let\hyper@anchorstart\HR@hyper@anchorstart
\let\hyper@anchorend\HR@hyper@anchorend
\let\hyper@linkstart\HR@hyper@linkstart
\let\hyper@linkend\HR@hyper@linkend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
This \verb+\ref+ will be linked regularly \ref{sec:intro}.\\
\hyperbypass
This one won't \ref{sec:intro}.\\
\hyperrestore
But, this one again \ref{sec:intro}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Uh! And `\ref*`?

Comment: Well. Yes... Let's say the document the OP is talking about contains to much `\ref`s and replacing the relevant ones with `\ref*` is not an option or not desired.

Comment: This might indeed be a use case.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, but it doesn't seem to work correctly for me. I am still getting errors related to hyperref in a part of the document that I am bypassing using these macros.

Answer (score 4):

The default `\label`-`\ref` system stores/retrieves *two* things associated with a label. The first is a counter, and the second is a page number. Technically, the label is created using (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
```

You'll see only `\@currentlabel` and `\thepage` being written to the `.aux` using `\protected@write`. When [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is loaded, it stores more than just two things. In fact, it stores (from [`nameref.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/nameref.dtx)):

```
\def\label#1{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \def\label@name{#1}%
    \label@hook
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \string\newlabel{#1}{%
        {\@currentlabel}%
        {\thepage}%
        {\@currentlabelname}%
        {\@currentHref}{}%
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}%
```

To cope with this redefinition of `\label` (which now stores *five* entries), `\ref` is also updated to *expect* *five* things, not two as you had perhaps thought.

Below I've provided an updated version of your MWE that seem to do what you're after, using [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount)'s `\getrefnumber` as an intermediary expandable counter-calculation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen,refcount,hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xifthen,refcount,hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\writeval}[2]{%
  \@bsphack%
  \setcounter{mycntr}{\numexpr\number#2-1}\refstepcounter{mycntr}%
  \label{#1}% Mark current label
  \@esphack%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{mycntr}

\begin{document}

\writeval{mylabel}{6}
mylabel = \ref{mylabel}

\begin{tabular}{c}%
  \setcounter{mycntr}{1}%
  \whiledo{\value{mycntr}<\getrefnumber{mylabel}}{%
    {\themycntr}\\ % 
    \stepcounter{mycntr}%
  }%
\end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

For ease-of-use, I've used a single counter and marked the reference using `\refstepcounter`. There are other ways of doing this (for example, copying the content from `\label` into your definition of `\writeval`, using only the important bits), but it was convenient in this case (assuming that you're only marking numbers).